# Microsoft Edge Cache Api Requests

Tags: angularjs, caching, browser-cache, mean-stack, microsoft-edge

I am having some issues with my eCommerce site when using Microsoft edge. The main issue I am having is during an angular `$http.get` request.

Generally the application flow is whenever the user visits the `/cart` page the browser makes a request to `/api/cart` which returns JSON with the contents of the cart along with pricing information.

The issue I am having is that when a product is added (on other pages) the session is correctly updating with the information, yet edge loads `/api/cart` with old information. Yet when you directly request `/api/cart` in another tab of edge the JSON loads correctly.

To clarify this incorrect behavior only occurs in Edge; Chrome and Firefox work as expected.

I'm using the MEAN stack for my development.

> TLDR: How do I prevent caching on an api JSON request in Edge

[image]

Comment: Also when you turn off cache in edge everything works property

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution was rather easy, just explicitly set the cache control to no-store.

```
  function nocache(req, res, next) {
      res.header('Cache-Control', 'private, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate');
      res.header('Expires', '-1');
      res.header('Pragma', 'no-cache');
      next();
  }
```

Above is a quick middleware function which will change a given request to a no-cache status.

Comment: It should be said that this was not an issue with edge specifically

Comment: Can you specify what file this goes in and what function it should be called from to fix the cart problem?

Comment: Has anyone been able to find out why Edge caches API requests in disk by default? I'm aware of the solution, I just would like to understand why Edge does that.